# Как в Go устроена установка модулей из сети?

Tags: golang, модули, установка

Go устанавливает модули из сети с помощью команды `go get ...`.

Но это не просто клонирование git-репозитория (не обязательно git). Так как например с сайта https://gitflic.ru, Go устанавливать модули не может, хотя `git clone ...` с этим сайтом работает.

То есть Go не просто клонирует репозиторий, а делает что-то ещё.

**Так всё-таки как устроена установка модулей из сети в GoLang?**

Comment: протокол [GOPROXY](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-proxy)